# Consumir WebService WSDL

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-service, wcf

Boa tarde,

Estou tentando consumir um WebService utilizando ASP.NET, porém, após adicionar a referencia do mesmo e executar o metodo, os parametros retornam nulo, gerando exception. Tentei executar através de WebRequest também, porém retornou o erro abaixo:

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.SystemSystem.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
```

Código

```
        string ret = String.Empty;
        string validade;
        erro erro = new erro();

        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(
        new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("utf-8", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11),
        new HttpTransportBindingElement());

        var sr = new SoapUraClient();
        sr.Endpoint.Binding = binding;

PARAMETROS //cnpjParceiro = 1234567890;codigoParceiro= 2; versaoWS = 1.0


        var teste = sr.GetToken(Convert.ToInt32(cnpjParceiro), Convert.ToInt32(codigoParceiro), versaoWS, out validade, out erro);

        ret = validade + '|' + erro.codErro + '|' + erro.codErro;
        return validade;
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: tentou adicionar como Service Reference?

Comment: Sim, tentei como Service Reference e enviando o XML com WebRequest. Se quiser, pode tentar executar, deixei os parâmetros no código.

Comment: deu problema no enconding do XML, o mesmo estava utilizando iso-8859-1.
Você pode ver a seguinte resposta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1908030/calling-a-webservice-that-uses-iso-8859-1-encoding-from-wcf

Comment: Ele alterou o formato para UTF-8, porém, agora o retorno é nulo. Utilizando SOAPUI consigo o retorno normalmente, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Obs: Isto não é uma resposta, mas sim uma analise detalhada da requisição.**

Acabei de testar este web-service.
Para tal eu adicionei o mesmo através de uma Web Reference e o fiz o chamei o mesmo da seguinte forma:

```
var token = String.Empty;
var validade = String.Empty;
var erro = default(UraService.erro);
try
{                
    var cliente = new UraService.SoapUraClient();
    cliente.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new SimpleEndpointBehavior());
    token = cliente.GetToken(1234567890, 2, "1.0", out validade, out erro);
}
catch (Exception err)
{ 
    Debugger.Break();
}
Debugger.Break();
```

Este Behavior tem a unica finalidade de inspecionar as mensagens sendo enviadas e recedidas. Segue abaixo a sua implementação:

**SimpleEndpointBehavior**

```
public class SimpleEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {

    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new SimpleMessageInspector());
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {

    }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {

    }
}
```

**SimpleMessageInspector**

```
public class SimpleMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
{
    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        var xml = reply.ToString();
        Debugger.Break();
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, IClientChannel channel)
    {
        var xml = request.ToString();
        Debugger.Break();
        return null;
    }
}
```

O Request está sendo enviado da seguinte forma:

**SoapUraService - Request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">get_token</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetToken xmlns="http://omnifacil3.omni.com.br/desenv">
      <cnpjParceiro xmlns="">1234567890</cnpjParceiro>
      <codigoParceiro xmlns="">2</codigoParceiro>
      <versaoWS xmlns="">1.0</versaoWS>
    </GetToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

E abaixo o response recebido:

**SoapUraService - Response**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <soap:Body>
<Response xmlns="http://omnifacil3.omni.com.br/desenv">
  <GetToken>
    <CodToken>499935661838159</CodToken>
    <ValidadeToken>12/02/2015 23:59:59</ValidadeToken>
  </GetToken></Response>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Acredito que o Cliente WCF está tendo problemas na hora de deserializar a mensagem, por isto está atribuindo null para token, validade e erro.

Se você olhar no arquivo WSDL, você encontrará os seguintes trechos:

**WSDL**

```
<portType name="SoapUra">
    <operation name="GetToken">
        <input message="tns:GetToken"/>
        <output message="tns:GetTokenResponse"/>
    </operation>
    <operation name="GetDadosAgente">
        <input message="tns:GetDadosAgente"/>
        <output message="tns:GetDadosAgenteResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
...
<xs:complexType name="GetToken">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="cnpjParceiro" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="codigoParceiro" type="xs:int" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element name="versaoWS" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">...</xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="GetTokenResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="CodToken" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">...</xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ValidadeToken" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">...</xs:element>
        <xs:element name="erro" type="tns:erro" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

**SoapUraService - Response Esperado**

Dá para se notar que o Response está num formato diferente do esperado pelo Cliente.
Abaixo segue o XML Esperado:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    <soap:Body>
        <GetTokenResponse xmlns="http://omnifacil3.omni.com.br/desenv">
            <CodToken>499935661838159</CodToken>
            <ValidadeToken>12/02/2015 23:59:59</ValidadeToken>
        </GetTokenResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Por fim, montei um Serviço WCF que imita o que você está tentando acessar, ele me retornou o Token e o ValidadeToken sem problemas, vou colocar abaixo as mensagens de envio e recebimento apenas para fins de comparação:

**WSTest - Request**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetToken</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <cnpjParceiro>1234567890</cnpjParceiro>
      <codigoParceiro>2</codigoParceiro>
      <versaoWS>1.0</versaoWS>
    </GetToken>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**WSTest - Response**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetTokenResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetTokenResult>499935661838159</GetTokenResult>
      <ValidadeToken>12/02/2015 23:59:59</ValidadeToken>
      <erro i:nil="true" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfService1" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
    </GetTokenResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Consegui simular aqui, é possível recuperar o xml retornado no behavior e trata-lo para capturar somente os parâmetros de retorno com xmlNode por exemplo?

Comment: Você pode manipular a mensagem de retorno no método .AfterReceiveReply() do MessageInspector, para isto basta manipular o objeto reply.

Comment: para isto você pode fazer o seguinte: reply = Message.CreateMessage(reply.Version, null, xmlReader);

Comment: E no momento que chamo o metodo GetToken (token = cliente.GetToken(1234567890, 2, "1.0", out validade, out erro);) Como capturo essa informação?

Comment: Assim que eu tiver um tempo, coloco uma resposta definitiva.